Did Sts. Joseph & Mary celebrate their nuptials?
As noted in this answer, the Jews had two ceremonies pertaining to marriage:

betrothal, "equivalent to our valid but not consummated marriage" (Llamera, O.P. p. 22), ≠ our engagement or future promise to marry
nuptials, solemnization of the marriage.

Sts. Joseph & Mary did not consummate their marriage, as she was a perpetual virgin (and so was St. Joseph); but did they have a nuptials, ceremony solemnizing their marriage, or do nuptials imply consummation?
If they did celebrate a nuptials ceremony, how many months after their betrothal did it occur?

Did you really mean "≠" (not equal)? I think you wanted one from notation - Difference between "≈", "≃", and "≅" - Mathematics Stack Exchange. (Or just say it in plain English.)

@RayButterworth Yes, the Jewish betrothal = marriage (the beginning of marriage). Their betrothal ≠ our engagement.

Did Sts. Joseph & Mary celebrate their nuptials?
Of course Mary and Joseph celebrated their nuptials. Traditionally the Church has always accepted this fact. How it actually played out is lost to history.
The Church in her understanding of the nuances of this unique marriage between St. Joseph and the Virgin Mary has instituted a feast on this very subject: Feast of the Holy Spouses celebrates the marriage of Joseph and Mary

The Espousals of the Blessed Virgin Mary or Marriage of the Virgin Mary is a Christian feast is celebrated by certain parts of the Roman Catholic Church such as the Oblates of Saint Joseph. It was formerly generally observed on January 23, but was removed from many local calendars by the Sacred Congregation of Rites.
In Matthew 1:16, Joseph is described as the husband of Mary. It is probable that Joseph and Mary were betrothed in Nazareth. The term "betrothal" indicates more than an engagement. It was customary in that time and place to celebrate marriage in two stages, the first being the contractual arrangements culminating in consent or "betrothal". After a period of around one year in which the couple were preparing for conjugal living, the second stage of actually conveying the wife to their new home would be accompanied by a great feast such as the Marriage Feast at Cana recounted in the John 2:1-11.
In 1416 Jean Gerson, Chancellor of the University of Paris urged the Council of Constance to establish a feast day honouring the Betrothal of Mary and Joseph, for which he wrote an office.
The first definite knowledge of a feast in honour of the espousals of Mary dates from August 29, 1517, when with nine other Masses in honour of Mary, it was granted by Leo X to the Nuns of the Annunciation, founded by Saint Jeanne de Valois. In certain particular churches the espousals of the Virgin Mary and St. Joseph are honoured with an office on January 23. The Oblates of St. Joseph celebrate January 23 as the feast of “The Holy Spouses Mary and Joseph”.
Gaspar Bertoni, founder of the Stigmatines, chose Mary and Joseph, in the context of their espousals, as patrons of the Congregation of the Sacred Stigmata. - Espousals of the Blessed Virgin Mary

Although no wedding feast is described for Our Lady and St. Joseph in the Bible, we should not assume that one did not occur. Matthew 1:24–25 says, “When Joseph awoke from sleep, he did as the angel of the Lord commanded him; he took her as his wife but had no marital relations with her until she had given birth to a son, and he named him Jesus.” Joseph taking “her as his wife” need not mean there was no feast. True it is not mentioned, but culture pressed for it. Besides that the family of Joseph and Mary with the Child Jesus had to have the marks that this was a regular Jewish family, thus not allowing the Devil to comprehend that Jesus was indeed the Christ. The historical testimonies suggest some sort of wedding celebration would have taken place—even given the extraordinary circumstances of Mary and Joseph’s courtship.

Betrothal: Meaning in Luke
Q: Can you provide some information regarding the term betrothal as used in Lk 1:27?
A: Betrothal: The first part of the two part process of Jewish marriage, which creates the legal relationship without the mutual obligations. In Hebrew it is called: kuddushin (sanctification). Kiddushin is far more binding than an engagement as we understand the term in modern English. Once kiddushin is complete the women is legally the wife of the man. The relationship created by kiddushin can only be dissolved by death or divorce. However the spouses do not live together at the time of the kiddushin, and the mutual obligations created by the marital relationship do not take effect until the nisuin is complete. The nisuin (elevation) finalizes the marriage process. The husband brings the wife into his home where they begin their married life together.

The following may be of interest to some:

Summa Theologica III Q 29. Of the espousals of the Mother of God

Holy Ring: The Wedding Band of the Blessed Virgin Mary



Espousal ≠ nuptials.

The Bible states that Joseph and Mary still were in a state of betrothal when the couple went to Bethlehem.
Luke 2

4 And Joseph too went up from Galilee from the town of Nazareth to
Judea, to the city of David that is called Bethlehem, because he was
of the house and family of David, 5 to be enrolled with Mary, his
betrothed, who was with child. 6 While they were there, the time came
for her to have her child, 7 and she gave birth to her firstborn son.

On this basis we can safely presume that they had not yet celebrated their nuptials. The reference to Joseph taking her to wife - which happened when Joseph was planning to divorce her - must mean that he continued to regard her as espoused to him despite her being pregnant. Since Luke implies that the birth took place very soon after their arrival in Bethlehem (no room at the inn), a nuptials ceremony could almost certainly not have happened before the birth.  Whether the couple held such a ceremony sometime after Jesus was born is not indicated in the Bible.

St. Thomas Aquinas, Summa Theologiae III q. 29 a. 2 ad 3 interprets Mt. 1:20:

Fear not to take unto thee Mary thy wife

as:

Fear not to solemnize your marriage with herne timeas nuptias eius solemniter celebrare"Fear not to celebrate her nuptials."


I don't think you answered your own follow-up question: "how many months after their betrothal did [the nuptials ceremony] occur?"  Nor did you clarify "do nuptials imply consummation".  An interesting question I might ask is whether from the view of the Catholic church today is whether such marriage is valid since perpetual virginity means there is no consummation, or whether their marriage is considered a special case.

@GratefulDisciple Good points. Thanks.

@GratefulDisciple "whether such marriage is valid since perpetual virginity means there is no consummation, or whether their marriage is considered a special case" Moral theologian John Cuthbert Ford, S.J., discussed this in his doctoral dissertation The Validity of Virginal Marriage (1938).
